# How to combine two variables from a json file in one row

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

**Situation:**
I have some json code in python 2.7 as follows:

```
[[u'2015-01-01', u'2015-01-02', u'2015-01-03'], {u'all': [200, 300, 400]}]
```

**Aim:**
My aim is to write this to a database like so:

```
'2015-01-01', 200
'2015-01-03', 300
'2015-01-03', 400
```

**Problem:**
How to combine with some kind of loop the python [list items] with corresponding {dictionary items}?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
d = [[u'2015-01-01', u'2015-01-02', u'2015-01-03'], {u'all': [200, 300, 400]}]

for item in zip(d[0], d[1]['all']):
    print item
```

Prints:

```
(u'2015-01-01', 200)
(u'2015-01-02', 300)
(u'2015-01-03', 400)
```